# What's the most direct way of creating a persistent live Ubuntu image file?

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, virtualization, persistence

I'm trying to create a persistent live Ubuntu image that I can use in VirtualBox.

I can create one from inside the guest, however, it's a very slow process, as, when done from scratch, it requires the installation of Ubuntu first.

I thought about using a loop device, however:

- tuxboot has no persistent option (but can list the loop device, if forced)
- mkusb doesn't recognize the device
- unetooting doesn't recognize the device (it's similar to tuxboot, but it has no force list option)

Is there any option?

If I could create the image with a loop device from the host, I could subsequently convert it to a VDI and use it in VirtualBox.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't just download a VDI?

Comment: Could you point me to a location? A simple search of `Ubuntu persistent live vdi` didn't yield any useful one.

Comment: https://www.osboxes.org/ provides VDIs for almost anything they can. I found something else: http://blog.sarim.me/2013/12/18/how-to-make-persistent-ubuntu-live-virtualbox-image/ that looks like it still can work.

Comment: Thanks. I'll verify them. I knew about the blog post; that doesn't work - it's Mac based, and when mounting a raw image as loop device on Linux, it's not recognized as disk according to the question details.

Comment: It has ready made Ubuntu. If your reason to want a live with persistence is to avoid installing the system as usual, that reason is no longer valid when you can download it already done.

Comment: I've made a very precise question; if none of you is able to answer precisely, it's better not to add comments with generic suggestions, which lead to timewaste. I've found the precise procedure, and I've put it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually very straightforward, with the right tool.

First, create a bootable flash key via any live media creation tool that supports persistent images (for example, `mkusb`).

Now, one can use `VBoxManage` to directly dump the key into a VDI image (after unmounting all the flash key partitions):

```sh
# Assumes that the device is /dev/sdb
VBoxManage convertfromraw -format VDI /dev/sdb ubuntu_live.vdi
```

Finally, attach the disk to the virtual machine IDE controller.

The live disk will now be booted by default.